# How can i show youtube video in exo player?

Tags: java, android, youtube, exoplayer

I want to show my youtube video in Exo player with custom controls in android with java and I also want to publish that app on the google play store. So can you please help me with a genuine way of doing this? So my app will not rejected soon when I upload that on google playstore

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily use Youtube url extractor repo to extract the mp4 url from youtube url than you can easily play that youtube video in exo player

Comment: Hi, do you know if it's still possible to use a Youtube url extractor to play a video into a third party player such as Exoplayer? It seems this way cannot be used anymore since 2021. Do you an example about a Youtube url extractor which would be working today? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need not worry about you app being rejected because until it follows googles policies, it won't remove your app.

And the requirement you want can be fulfilled [with this library](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player). **This will not increase app size more than 1 MB.**
It also it customisable just like you want.

This is how you can implement it.

1.In your build.gradle, add this dependency

`implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'`

2.In your layout xml file add the following code

```
<com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:autoPlay="true"
    app:showFullScreenButton="false" />
```

3.In your activity add the following code

```
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
getLifecycle().addObserver(youTubePlayerView);
```

4.To load the video add this

```
youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
  @Override
  public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
      //if your url is something like this -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzyXVfyx7CU
      String urlToLoad = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzyXVfyx7CU";
      String[] url = urlToLoad.split("watch?v=");
      youTubePlayer.loadVideo(url[1], 0);
      //if your url is something like this -> EzyXVfyx7CU
      String videoId = "EzyXVfyx7CU";
      youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
  }
});
```

Now to add customisations, you can follow the following links.

[Toggle auto link](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#autoPlay)

[Enable automatic initialization](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#enableAutomaticInitialization)

[Handle UI Events](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#handleNetworkEvents)

[Add Web UI](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#useWebUi)

[Toggle live video UI](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#enableLiveVideoUi)

[Show YouTube Button](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#showYouTubeButton)

[Toggle Full Screen](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#showFullScreenButton)

[Show video current time](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#showVideoCurrentTime)

[Show video description](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#showVideoDuration)

[Show seekbar](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#showSeekBar)

If you are thinking that you can fully customise the UI,you cannot do it any way.This library also provides only option on the left and right side and the top and bottom of the pause/play button.It will look something like this.

[image]

Comment: but i want to play youtube video in my custom Exo player

Comment: why, you can use this library.It is also customisable!!And from my point of view ,dont use exo player as it took me 8 mins for loading an 2 min video with a constant network speed of 250-300 mbps

Comment: is this library increase my app size

Comment: can you plz provide me the code of this library with customization

Comment: I have edited my answer and not it shows how to implement.

Comment: is it is possible to add custom controller in video view like exo player ?

Comment: becz i want my custom controllers on it !

Comment: I have not used this library so I cannot tell